# hashmap iterator when used inside synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

so let's say I have a Hashmap that looks like:

key            :  value

(string 1, queue 1)

(string 2, queue 2)

(string 3, queue 3)

I also have a synchronized method that will access this hashmap, and an iterator is created inside the method:

```
 Iterator it = hashmap.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext()){
      Queue q = it.next();
      QueueItem item = q.get(0);
      return item;
 }
```

Now I have 2 threads calling this method, when thread 1 calls, it will get an iterator that points to (string 1, queue 1); my question is when thread 2 calls, will the iterator points to (string 1, queue 1) or (string 2, queue 2)?

Comment: Neither. Making a method `synchronized` implies that *at most one thread can execute it*. The second thread has to wait for the other thread to finish the method execution completely before entering the method. All that assuming that the two threads are invoking the method on the same object.

Comment: So what if the method doesn't iterate over the whole hashmap? for exmaple, it will only get a item from the queue. Thank you

Comment: As [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30871810/2711488) says, a new `Iterator` is created on each execution, hence the state of a previous `Iterator` is completely irrelevant. So each fresh new iterator is capable of iterating over all entries of the map, but you may terminate earlier if you wish.

Comment: `hashmap.iterator()` won't compile.  You probably meant `hashmap.values().iterator()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling *iterator()* creates a **new** Iterator positionned at the begin of the collection, so it will always give you the first entry of you Map implementation.

When using HashMap, ordering is undefined, but you can use other Map implementations to control the ordering (LinkedHashMap, TreeMap, ...)

Comment: We’re talking about a **HashMap**, so there is no guaranty which pair will be the first one, but the only thing that matters is that the `Iterator` will always iterate over *all* values.

Comment: @Holger is right, HashMap can't garantee any ordering, but LinkedHashMap will keep the original insertion ordering. You can also use a TreeMap to have a natural ordering (using Comparable keys)

Comment: @Toilal just edit the part where you talk about iteration order, Holger knows for sure how maps in java work

Comment: The ordering in hash maps is completely random and *not* based on hashcodes! As a matter of fact the ordering can change over time (due to resizing operations, but that's an implementation detail if a rather unavoidable one)

Comment: @Adam Technically "random" would be acceptable since the docs make no guarantees, but you're obviously right - arbitrary it should be.